# BaseExpandableListAdapter - getChildView random position

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I'm fiddling with my custom BaseExpandableListAdapter and in my getChildView method I seem to get random positions of child views. I get random order of positions regardless of recycling. For instance, in the convertView = null conditional branch I get:

LogCat prints in the (ConvertView==null):

childPosition﹕ childPosition - 0
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 1
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 0
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 3
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 4
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 0

LogCat prints in the (ConvertView!=null):

childPosition﹕ childPosition - 1
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 2
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 3
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 4
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 5
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 6
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 7
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 8
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 0
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 1
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 0
childPosition﹕ childPosition - 1

Here is the code for my adapter:

```
public class MyExapndableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> headerList;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public MyExapndableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this.headerList = listDataHeader;

        Log.d("LIST CHILD", "" + _listDataChild.size());
        Log.d("LIST HEADER", "" + this.headerList.size());
    }


    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.headerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this.headerList.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return this.headerList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this.headerList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.addView(v.findViewById(R.id.blaGroup));
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        MyText title = (MyText) holder.getView(R.id.blaGroup);
        title.setText(headerTitle);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {

//            Log.d("NULL VIEW", "childText - " +childText);
            Log.d("childPosition", "childPosition - " +childPosition);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, null);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            final float GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP = 30.0f;

            // Convert the dips to pixels
            final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int pixel = (int) (GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP * scale + 0.5f);

            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/pacifico.ttf");
            int fontColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.testColor);
            int strokeWidth = 5;
            int strokeColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.card_white);

            // Add TextView on the fly
            MyText text = new MyText(context, pixel, childText, font, fontColor, strokeWidth, strokeColor);
            text.setLayoutParams(lp);
            text.setText(childText);
            text.setTextSize(GESTURE_THRESHOLD_DIP);
            text.setId(3005);

            ((ViewGroup) row).addView(text);


            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.addView(text);
            row.setTag(holder);



        }

        else {
//            Log.d("NOT NULL VIEW", "childText - " +childText);
            Log.d("NOT NULL VIEW childPosition", "childPosition - " +childPosition);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        MyText text = (MyText) holder.getView(3005);
        text.setText(childText);

        return row;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        private HashMap<Integer, View> storedViews = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

        public ViewHolder() {
        }

        public ViewHolder addView(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            storedViews.put(id, view);
            return this;
        }

        public View getView(int id) {
            return storedViews.get(id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i2) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting wrong item using getchild method.

Answer (score 0):

You get a random position because you are using a **Hashmap**. Hashmap has its own way on sorting data inside it. So I recommend using a custom object than a Hashmap.

Comment: @Yosi199 I guess he's talking about extending a `List`, and making the "key finding" by yourself, but working on a `List<View>`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. If your `_listDataChild` is just a list of string, you can use array of string instead. Take a look in this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well the childView's positions are not random , its just that they are child positions from different groups ,print them along with groupId's you will understand whats happening . Also the childPosition doesn't depend on whether the convertview is null or not , usually getChildView is called for the list item which will be coming onto the screen while scrolling.
Hope this helps , revert back if you want an example .